# Getting the integer from a string in form of a comma separated/decorated number?

Tags: php

I am parsing a stream of strings like `'1,985'` and I want to convert them to the respective integer, like `1985` in this case.

Is there any built-in/efficient PHP function which does that?

Comment: Is there any encapsulating symbol/character? http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php comes to mind but if you have no encapsulation there's no way to tell thousands from millions, etc.

Comment: You can use `intval()`, `number_format`..

Comment: Use `preg_replace` to replace anything that is not a digit to `""`

Comment: Or just [`numfmt_parse`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php)

Comment: @mario, Can you please give an example how can we use `numfmt_parse`, I want to learn. I make [this](https://3v4l.org/Ll1r4)

Comment: @RivnatNasah Use `"en_EN"` as input style specifier.

Comment: The return type is float, Is there any way to get int value?? as because OP want int, If then i will update my answer with this functionality. I just love that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `intval` and `str_replace` for getting your desire result. Intval for your integer number and str_replace for remove the comma from string.

```
$str = '1,985';
var_dump(intval(str_replace(",", "", $str))); //int(1985)
```

Comment: I used a variant of this as  
(int)(str_replace(',','',$str);